# JetBrains TeamCity API call to change MAIN_NODE

Tags: rest, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

According to the guides on JetBrains website, there is an RESTAPI call to change the MAIN_NODE owner. I've tried this (`/app/rest/server/nodes/id:[NODEID]/enabledResponsibilities/MAIN_NODE`) but it does not enable the MAIN_NODE role. IF the node is already MAIN_NODE, it will remove the MAIN_NODE role, so you can say that "disable" works, but "enable" does not..

Anyone tried this ?

TeamCity version is the latest 2023.05 (build 129203)

```
/app/rest/server/nodes/id:[NODEID]/enabledResponsibilities/MAIN_NODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your use case is the same as described in [TeamCity forums](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11958305323282-Change-main-node-using-rest-api-does-not-work?page=1#community_comment_12101175462546), this should work:

```
$uri = "http://<SERVERNAME>/app/rest/server/nodes/id:<NODEID>/enabledResponsibilities/MAIN_NODE"
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer <TOKEN>"}
$contentType = "text/plain"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $uri -ContentType $contentType -Headers $headers -Body "true"
```